# FAST Search JDBC Connector crawling/indexing multiple docs

Tags: fast-search

we configured FAST JDBC Connector with Oracle database for crawling/indexing, as far as I know that JDBC connector doesnt support documents (like PDF, Word, Excel). We have another system using this Oracle DB and store items, and we may have multiple docs in one item and now need to crawl/index in FAST.

We create a python script to do that and using getPath and into Data property, however we can only get one document not all docs. How to write the python stage in order to support it?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this FAST ESP or FAST for SharePoint 2010?

Comment: It's FAST for sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom bcs connector handling that - what you are trying to do is definitely possible. See this example as a starter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff625800(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks Max! BCS is not a option here since we are not using SharePoint 2010 just FAST Search as Enterprise Search Center. I am not good at coding so want to know how this method done. Thank you.